# Custom content type throwing errors?

Tags: content-type, visual-studio, field-definition

I have created a custom content type that uses several custom fields that I created in the same project.

When I deploy the content type for the first time it works fine.  When I try to deploy subsequent versions it errors out during the deploy from visual studio with:

> The field with Id
>   {ef6deded-1c4f-484d-8f5d-98890ebb6d66}
>   defined in feature
>   {45157d10-6480-4311-ad90-f9df4b896f8a}
>   was found in the current site
>   collection or in a subsite.

How can I get around this?  Can I not update a custom content type after I have deployed it?

Comment: What do you mean by subsequent version? Are you using FEATURE versioning? what's the "Deployment Conflict Resolution" property (VS.NET property window) of Content Type Node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it correct you didn't install VS2010 SP1? After installation of SP1 I don't think it will happen again. When you're not able to install it now, you can restart Visual Studio and try to deploy the solution again.

Comment: Yeah rebooting fixed it.  How do I check with Service packs have been installed?

Comment: I guess you have to check the Help->About screen.

Comment: Yeah, thats where I looked.  Didn't see anything one way or the other.  Must be SP1